# Generalization of Doob Dynkin for Stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be continuous time stochastic process and $\{\mathcal{F}_t^X\}_{t \geq 0}$ be the filtration generated by it. If the process $Y$ is $\{\mathcal{F}_t^X\}_{t \geq 0}$ adapted, is there any simple representation of the process $Y$ in terms of $X$. This will be a generalization of [Doob Dynkin Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a non-trivial result in the general setting, but for some special cases of $X_t$ and $Y_t$ it is possible to represent $Y_t$ as an Ito integral w.r.t. $X_t$, see for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the trivial consequence of Doob-Dynkin's lemma that for each $t$ there exists some measurable function $u_t$ such that $Y_t=u_t(X_s;s\leqslant t)$... Since every $(Y_t)$ thus defined satisfies the hypothesis, I doubt one can go much further.